# Is having research experience in interdisciplinary team beneficial for graduate admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I just applied for M.Sc. in Computer Science at University of Toronto in Canada, which is considered a very competitive program. I also graduated from one of the top Canadian universities, McGill. My research interest is in the area of machine learning. I majored in Computer Science, minored in mathematics.

I have two research experiences (one is related to ML). I had three supervisors (two from non-CS, one CS). We were conducting research in an interdisciplinary   team of doctors, physicists, and computer scientists. Unfortunately, my CS supervisor recently passed away due to cancer, so I have two Letter of Recommendation from non-CS supervisors. I believe that LORs are strong since I have known them for awhile and I have good relationships with them. But I wonder 
how admission committees will view my application if I have LORs from non cs faculty? Is having research experience in interdisciplinary team beneficial for graduate admission? I am sure they are pretty reputable in their own studies, and my CS supervisor was also pretty reputable.

Comment: welcome Ted! I believe parts of your question (like your grades) are not really relavant to your question. I would suggest editing them out just to avoid red flags.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be fine, regardless, but you could probably do the following. Find a CS prof with whom you did well and get a letter from them. Ask them to mention that your main CS advisor recently passed and can't write on your behalf.

But if they can also say that they hold you in high regard based on past contacts it will not seem quite so overbalanced. Perhaps one of them (in CS) also discussed you with the deceased prof, so you get a second-hand recommendation.

However, interdisciplinary work can be highly valued, depending on what you want to do, and where. If you want to stay at that intersection you may not need much in the way of a boost for CS.

Comment: I stated the name of CS prof in the statement of purpose. I expressed my gratitude to her for guidance as an additional note, but I didn't explicitly say she passed away because I wasn't sure if it was appropriate.

Comment: It is probably good if someone does, not you necessarily. Someone might wonder why there is no letter from her.

Comment: There's nothing I could do at this point since I already submitted it. I'm just hoping that one of my referees acknowledges her in the letter.